# Can't background-size settings be dissociated from background image?

Tags: html, css

Ttrying to reduce size of my CSS file, I wanted to factorize some commands such as `background-size`. Let's say I have plenty of sections like this:

```
#interlude {
  background: url(https://.../unsplash.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

In use:

```
<div id="interlude"></div>
```

If I have many different "interlude" divs, all the size-related lines in CSS are duplicated. I'd like to get something like that:

```
#interlude {
  background: url(https://.../unsplash.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
}
.bw-back-cover {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

In this case, `bw-back-cover` class is declared only once. But it doesn't work and I don't know of it's a normal behavior or not.

Both cases on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbzWwJ)

Comment: You can't have multiple `interlude`'s divs. At least not with the same `id`.

Comment: @crazymatt, it seems from the codepen that is there.

Comment: yeah i saw it afterwards so I removed my comment. For a quick and dirty fix you can overwrite the ID class if you add the "important" rule to your class but I dont really recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of your CodePen, the shorthand `background` property is overriding **all** background-related properties, not just the ones specified - so `background-size` is being ignored because `background` has a higher priority (being on an ID vs. a class).

There are two ways to fix this.

1) The simple way is to add `!important` to each line of the `background-size` property so they aren't overwritten by the `background` shorthand. (However, I would suggest the second solution below, as `!important` is difficult to override if needed.) Code:

```
.bw-back-cover {
  -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
  -moz-background-size: cover !important;
  -o-background-size: cover !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

2) The cleaner fix would be to split out your background properties instead of using the shorthand, so `background-size` is not overwritten. Code:

```
#interlude {
  background-image: url(https://.../unsplash.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Although I hate your explanation, this is the right answer. There is nothing "hacky" about **!important**

This type of scenario is the exact reason why the call exists. He should be putting all his normal calls on his IDs and then have a class setup with the important tag. The point that the class is specifically set out to change only one specific piece, is why the !important is mandated. The naming convention also, aligns well with the type of setup for an !important call.

Comment: @jjeining You're right - if this class exists for the sole purpose of adding `background-size` to any element, then `!important` is not hacky here. I'm just used to discouraging use of it because it's difficult to override, but you're correct that this is one situation where that's not applicable.